# MVC map viewmodel to domain model (without automapper) for edit action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have nothing against automapper, but would like to understand the manual method first.

My table that will be updated is area_list

My viewmodel:

```
 public class AreaView
{
    public int area_id { get; set; }
    public string area_name { get; set; }
    public string facility_name { get; set; }
    public int facility_id { get; set; }
}
```

The Edit view has two fields, area_id (hidden) and area_name

My Edit controller (post), which is where my question is:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(AreaView e_area)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            areaDB.Entry(e_area).State = EntityState.Modified;
            areaDB.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("List", new { id = e_area.facility_id });
        }
        return View(e_area);
    }
```

Could someone provide an example of how to manually map the viewmodel to the area_list (model, created by entity framework)?  Am I binding the AreaView viewmodel correctly?

This would be in the controller for now, though if it should reside somewhere else, all ears.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, more trial and error came to the answer, posted below if it's useful for anyone else.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(AreaView e_area)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Map the model 

            var area = areaDB.area_list.Where(x => x.area_id == e_area.area_id).FirstOrDefault();
            area.area_name = e_area.area_name;

            areaDB.Entry(area).State = EntityState.Modified;
                areaDB.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("List", new { id = e_area.facility_id });
        }
        return View(e_area);
    }
```